# Chrome extension: Can't make chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia capture window audio

Tags: google-chrome-extension, web-audio-api

I'm trying to use the `chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia` API in order to capture audio from the extension window.

I'm sending the capture request from the popup.js page.

Manifest:

```
{
"background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "style/icons/icon16.png",
    "default_title": "__MSG_name__"
},
"default_locale": "en",
"description": "__MSG_description__",
"icons": {
    "128": "style/icons/icon128.png"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "__MSG_extName__",
"permissions": ["activeTab","desktopCapture"],
"offline_enabled": true,
"short_name": "__MSG_short__",
"version": "1.0.9"
```

}

function:

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["window"], function (streamId) {
        var audioStream = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
        });
        audioStream.then(function (mediaStream) {...}
```

I have tried using different parameters, but whenever I omit: `audio:true`, I get :

> Failed to execute 'getUserMedia' on 'MediaDevices': At least one of
>   audio and video must be requested(…).

The following code doesn't appear in the API, but I've read about it here and tried it, the previous error applies to it as well:

```
audio: {
  mandatory: {
       chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
       chromeMediaSourceId: streamId
       }
     }
```

When I do use `audio:true`, it records the mic, even though I get the source window selection dialog.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesnt look like recording window audio is supported, only for tabs and screens. You also need to pass "audio" in the capture types array.

Comment: @DanielHerr Thank you, will the "screen" parameter record the system output, after I add the "audio" parameter? Also, are the mandatory parameters correct?

Comment: Check the source of this sample: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdamcnkmddbfhaadidkhahllkabienpk

Comment: @DanielHerr I will, thanks again!

Comment: Looking at that source, `["window"]` is the only selector that does NOT allow audio capture. Both tab and screen do. Curious.

Comment: @Xan After experimenting with the code a bit, it seems to me like the only way to capture the system audio is through the video parameter. I wasn't able to capture a non-mic audio using the audio parameter. The "screen recorder" app is doing the same thing - system audio is recorded because the video is always enabled.

Comment: Worth documenting in a self-answer for sure.

Answer (score 2):

After experimenting with the code a bit, it seems to me like the only way to capture the system audio is through the video parameter. I wasn't able to capture a non-mic audio using the audio parameter. The [screen recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdamcnkmddbfhaadidkhahllkabienpk) app is doing the same thing - system audio is recorded through the video.

Comment: It looks like there is now an issue for audio-only capture: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=769388